# Rebind .toggle() event after unrelated event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a filter for a grid that is being shown/hidden with toggle like so:

```
$("#btnFilter").toggle(function () {
    // show filter
}, function () {
    // hide filter
});
```

The grid is interactive and double-clicking it will overlay the existing grid with new dynamic HTML.  I do not want my filter to be shown when interacting with the grid, so in my grids onClick() event I am putting the appropriate `// hide filter` code which is the same as in the toggle function.

The only issue is, since I am bypassing the .toggle() event, I'll need to click on #btnFilter twice when attempting to hide it manually (which is what I do not want).

Any thoughts would be great!

I appreciate the answers but the logic isn't really what concerns me, any idea why toggle has been removed?  Possibly related to my issue?

Comment: toggle is removed in new jquery version use some another logic

Comment: @Rituraj ratan I didn't know that, thanks for the heads up.  Any idea why they removed it?

Comment: bse sometimes it creates  problem get more detail from http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[toggle(function,function...)](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed) is removed, create a bool and use an if statement

```
var toggle = false;
$('#btnFilter').on('click', function () {
    toggle = !toggle;
    if (toggle) {} else {}
});
```

*toggle(function,function...) remove because:*

> This is the "click an element to run the specified functions"
>   signature of .toggle(). It should not be confused with the "change the
>   visibility of an element" of .toggle() which is not deprecated. The
>   former is being removed to reduce confusion and improve the potential
>   for modularity in the library. The jQuery Migrate plugin can be used
>   to restore the functionality.

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted...this is the closest thing to the answer I was looking for.  I'll accept in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle is removed you can use a boolean variable or just ask jQuery if it's visible

```
$('#btnFilter').on('click', function () {
    if ($("#filterDiv").is(":visible")) {
        $("#filterDiv").hide();
    } else {
        $("#filterDiv").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Clicking on `#btnFilter` clearly doesn't hide itself, so `$(this)` isn't correct; I suppose it works for the purposes of an example though.

Comment: A shorter version would be `var div = $("#filterDiv"); div.toggle(!div.is(":visible"));`